# Highmaps - How to remove canary islands from spain highlight

Tags: highcharts

I am using highmaps with the custom world mapdata. Only Spain is being highlighted in my example. However, when you mouseover the country Spain some islands to the north of Africa highlight as well. I suspect that these are the Canary Islands. How do I prevent these Islands from being highlighted?
Example:
http://bastionstudio.co.za/test/spain.html

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved by pushing new coordinates for Spain.
http://bastionstudio.co.za/test/spain-no-canary-islands.html

```
console.log(Highcharts.maps['custom/world'].features);

Highcharts.maps['custom/world'].features.push({
   "type":"Feature",
   "id":"ES",
   "properties": {
          "hc-group":"admin0",
          "hc-middle-x":0.76,
          "hc-middle-y":0.27,
          "hc-key":"es",
          "hc-a2":"ES","name":"Spain",
          "labelrank":"2",
          "country-abbrev":"Sp.",
          "subregion":"Southern Europe",
          "region-wb":"Europe & Central Asia",
          "iso-a3":"ESP","iso-a2":"ES","woe-id":"23424950",
          "continent":"Europe"
    },
    "geometry":{
       "type":"MultiPolygon",
       "coordinates":[
    [
     [
      [4045, 7594],
      [4021, 7599],
      [4011, 7621],
      [3984, 7629],
      [3997, 7692],
      [3998, 7762],
      [4020, 7781],
      [4009, 7795],
      [3944, 7795],
      [3930, 7838],
      [3969, 7860],
      [3988, 7852],
      [4098, 7851],
      [4151, 7846],
      [4203, 7821],
      [4246, 7818],
      [4249, 7812],
      [4255, 7814],
      [4262, 7812],
      [4262, 7813],
      [4262, 7814],
      [4263, 7812],
      [4263, 7812],
      [4279, 7808],
      [4298, 7812],
      [4300, 7795],
      [4265, 7771],
      [4233, 7763],
      [4194, 7709],
      [4211, 7683],
      [4189, 7669],
      [4183, 7644],
      [4154, 7635],
      [4143, 7615],
      [4072, 7613],
      [4046, 7594],
      [4045, 7594]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom map: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

or remove Canary Islands from the point graphic, but then they will completely disappear from the map:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var point = this.series[0].points[0],
                    pathArr = point.graphic.attr('d').split('M');

                pathArr.shift();

                point.graphic.attr({
                    'd': 'M' + pathArr[3]
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6oa08vyd/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr